# how to change ionic app version using xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to change my ionic app version when i add a new release to my git repo. In order to achieve this I executing `xmlstarlet ed -L -u 'widget\@version' -v '<tag value>' config.xml` but the output came with nothing changed. I have already tried the xpath expression and it find the node.
this is 'config.xml' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="io.ionic.my_app" version="1.0.3">
...
</widget>
```

If I remove the properties `xmlns` and `xmlns:cdv` it works, why those properties affects how `xmlstarlet` works and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this problem happens because of the use of namespaces. It can be fixed by adding a namespace property to `xmlstarlet` using option `-N`
the command would get like this

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N N='http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets' -u 'N:widget/@version' -v '1.0.10' config.xml
```

As you can see we add N: to the xpath